# VALIDAR FORMULARIO JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

gente tengo un problema no puedo ejecutar bien el codigo y no hace lo que deveria, lo que se supone que deve hace es validar que todos los campos esten rellenados pero cuando ejecuto el codigo y pongo campos sigue diciendome lo mismo de que los campos no estan llenos porfavor alguien ayudeme

```js
const datos = {
    nombre: "",
    email: "",
    mensaje: ""
};

const nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre");
const email = document.querySelector("#email");
const mensaje = document.querySelector("#mensaje");
const formulario = document.querySelector(".formulario");

formulario.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { nombre, email, mensaje } = datos;

    if(nombre === "" || email === "" || mensaje === "" ){
        console.log("Todos los campos son obligatorios");

        return;
    }

    console.log("enviando formulario");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema en tu código está en que estas verificando los datos que declaras en tu variable datos declarada al inicio y no los datos del formulario.

Al igual que en tu código tampoco estas recuperando los valores de tus inputs.

Te dejo tu código modificado el cual debería funcionar,  te recomiendo declarar la variable datos que imagino es la que enviaras a tu backend una vez ya validado los campos de tu formulario que es cuando la vas a utilizar. También te recomiendo que verifiques directamente el valor de los inputs aprovechando que ya tienes estos declarados.

```js
const nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre");
const email = document.querySelector("#email");
const mensaje = document.querySelector("#mensaje");
const formulario = document.querySelector(".formulario");

formulario.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(nombre.value === "" || email.value === "" || mensaje.value === "" ){
        console.log("Todos los campos son obligatorios");

        return;
    }

    const datos = {
        nombre: nombre.value,
        email: email.value,
        mensaje: mensaje.value
    };
    console.log("enviando formulario");
});
```

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias bro me ayudaste con esto te agradezco

Answer (score 0):

es importante que tomes en consideración que no estás accediendo al valor del campo, simplemente estás tomando toda la etiqueta input.

En ese caso, es importante que agregues la propiedad **value** al finalizar el input:

```
const nombre = document.getElementById("#nombre").value;
const email = document.getElementById("#email").value;
const mensaje = document.getElementById("#mensaje").value;
```

Comment: no me sirvio men creo que esta mal

Comment: Verifica usándolo de esa manera.